# reactjs retrieve all children refs parent event (handleSubmit)

Tags: reactjs, events, children, refs

```
<Parent> /* event to fetch all refs value and submit */
  <Child>
     <stateless function />/*this is all the refs sittin*/
  </Child>
</Parent>
```

i don't know how parent can get all refs from the child ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add the code with example input and expected outputrather than you structure.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's perhaps too late and you already knew the answer.
What you need is a "ref", a reference to the children.
Read this: [Exposing DOM Refs to Parent Components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#exposing-dom-refs-to-parent-components)

Something like this:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        // this line will create a reference to the input text,
        // inside the Child Component
        // for example, if you want to get the value 
        // you can access `this.input.value`
        <Child inputRef={(refToChild) => this.input = refToChild} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Child extends React Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        // this line will call the Parent's function,
        // creating a reference to the input text.
        <input type="text" ref={props.inputRef} />
      </form>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide more details on the solution, possibly with code example rather than links which should just support the answer.

Comment: Please check my revised answer.